# XML parsing with java, with out using pre-defined libraries

Tags: java, jaxb

Can Someone tell me , How to do XML parsing with java (JAXB).

Comment: What do you mean with "That too with own libraries only"?

Comment: Do you want to use DOM? SAX? StAX? JAXB? XPath? There is no possible way to answer this question.

Comment: Why would you ever want to parse XML by hand? That is a very complicated operation, that's why there are many libraries out there for working with XML.

Comment: Please read the Help Center

Comment: Sorry yar i forgot to mention that , It is using JAXB...

Comment: I would suggest you [Google a tutorial](http://bit.ly/1Bfcrgf).

Comment: i've gone through some pdfs too, But not getting the rit one for this. Actually using library file i've done it n executed also, But without using libraries , I'm not getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html (see Basic Example)

Quick and dirty snippet to start with (plain java, no external dependencies):

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class XmlParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Pair.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader("<pair><a>Hello</a><b>World</b></pair>"));
        System.out.println(o);
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Pair {
        public String a;
        public String b;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pair{" + "a='" + a + '\'' + ", b='" + b + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by no means this is replacement to JAXP and JAXB documentation :)